# Why are these circles things appearing on my canvas thing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

http://codepen.io/Yonkai/pen/PmyJZK

YMMV, but to me to me these weird circle things appear the right on the animation inside the triangly part, is this an artifact of my the code, computer screen (assuming you see it also), canvas, codepen, the programming, an optical illusion? Is there a name for this? Not sure why it's appearing.

```
// Creating canvas object and setting context.
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    
// Setting canvas height and width to height and width of the canvas.
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

// Declaring the row size, matrix info >none here<, font size which correlates to font size.
var matrix = " "; 
matrix = matrix.split(" ");
var font_size = 5;  
var rows = c.height / font_size;
var drops = [];

// First row setup
for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) 
{
  drops[x] = 1; 
}

function draw() {  
  
  // Screen Refresh
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.001)"; 
  ctx.fillRect(1, 1, c.width,c.height); 
  
  //Determines color, moddable if you understand HEX colors.
   function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0F';
    var color = '#';
    var grayscale = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
    for (var i = 0; i <6; i++) {
      color += grayscale; 
    }
    return color;
  }
 
  // When matrix used.
  ctx.font = font_size + "px Courier New";

  // Advances rows or columns across the screen, technically asynchronous but happens so fast
  // it doesn't appear to me.
  for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) 
  {
    ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    var text = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)]; 
      
    // Random value in the matrix array.
    ctx.fillText(text, drops[i] * font_size,font_size * i); 
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(c.width/2,c.height/2);
    ctx.lineWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 3;  
    ctx.lineTo( drops[i] * font_size,font_size * i);
    ctx.strokeStyle = getRandomColor();
    ctx.stroke();
   
    //Makes a uniform picture by switching the overlay type halfway through the canvas picture.
    if (drops[i] * font_size > (c.width/2) ) {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    }
    
    // Resets rows, currently redraws under screen so does little, but useful for modification.
    if (drops[i] * font_size > c.width && Math.Random() > 0.9 ) {
        drops[i] = 0;
    }

    drops[i]++;
  }
}

// 'Tick' rate of animation.
setInterval(draw, 300);
```

Comment: lookup `moire` patterns

Comment: For convenience, here is the wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Jaromanda X, this problem seems to be [moire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) patterns, which result from the high contrast lines being too close together (so that they approach the Nyquist frequency). To fix this, there are computer graphics concepts such as linear filtering (which essentially calculates pixel colors based on weighted averages of nearby pixel colors).

However, for a more simple fix, you can increase the distance between the scanning lines by decreasing the amount of such lines emanating towards the text, or perhaps try using lines with less contrast (shades of gray or other colors).